# List of all past comet passes and area it was visible?

Tags: resource-recommendations, astronomy, soft-question, comets

Is there a database/website which shows all comets which have passed Earth and have been viewed? Is there any country specific viewing database as well?

I would like to do a search on the lines of : Show me all comets were visible from India during 1950 to 1960?

Any searches on Google have not returned anything, so querying this exchange site.

Comment: No idea about a specific directory, but there's a database of comets in Stellarium which shows realtime positions of all known comets. You can program a script to find all comets which have been viewed from Earth(visible in sky) and where.
Does that help you a bit?

Comment: I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

I would try here, generate an ephemeris for the object of interest (some objects may already be in the database.)

[HORIZONS Web-Interface](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi)

This tool provides a web-based limited interface to JPL's HORIZONS system which can be used to generate ephemerides for solar-system bodies. Full access to HORIZONS features is available via the primary telnet interface. HORIZONS system news shows recent changes and improvements. A web-interface tutorial is available to assist new users.